Is this Dirichlet type function Riemann Integrable?
\begin{cases}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right) &,\quad \text{if } x \text{ is rational}
\\
0 &,\quad \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
Over the interval $[0,1]$
My approach

Solve for upper and lower integral. But was unable to somehow account for the 3 different types of intervals possible(both rational and irrational $x$ , only rational $x$ and only irrational $x$)

I was unable to find a partition of $f(x)$ for which $U(p,f) - L(p, f) < ε$ is NOT satisfied. (I tried for $[0.4, 0.5]$)



My best guess would be that this function is $0$ $\lambda$-a.e. thus the integral is 0. In particular, I think this is not Riemann integrable, but it is Lebesgue integrable.
